# Option[io.databaker.env.EnvValue], but type F is invariant in type

Tags: scala, scala-cats

I have the following code snippet, that does not get compiled:

```
trait Environment[F[_]] {
  def get(v: EnvVariable): F[Option[EnvValue]]
}

final class LiveBadEnvironment[F[_] : Sync] extends Environment[F] {
  override def get(v: env.EnvVariable): F[Option[env.EnvValue]] = None.pure[F]
}
```

the compiler complains:

```
[error]  found   : F[None.type]
[error]  required: F[Option[io.databaker.env.EnvValue]]
[error]     (which expands to)  F[Option[io.databaker.env.EnvValue.Type]]
[error] Note: None.type <: Option[io.databaker.env.EnvValue], but type F is invariant in type _.
[error] You may wish to define _ as +_ instead. (SLS 4.5)
[error]   override def get(v: env.EnvVariable): F[Option[env.EnvValue]] = None.pure[F]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have changed to override `def get(v: env.EnvVariable): F[Option[env.EnvValue]] = F.pure(None)` and got the error message `not found: value F`. What am I doing wrong?

Consider how the name `F` is used in `implicit F: Applicative[F]`

```
def foo[F[_]](implicit F: Applicative[F]): F[Option[String]] = F.pure(None)
        |              |              |                        |
      type           value          type                 "type as value"
```

Note how the **value** parameter `F` has the **same** name as the **type** parameter `F`. Now calling a method on value `F` looks like as if we are calling a method on a type

```
F.pure(None)
```

Invoking a method on a type using dot syntax is not possible in Scala, but conceptually that is what we are doing - we wish to convey the idea of invoking a "type-level" function. This [naming convention](https://gitter.im/scala/scala?at=5ee5151d2cf2f36eae59978f) works because values and types live in two separate universes so we can reuse the same name without clashes. For example, consider why the following is legal

```
scala> object f { def f[f](f: f): f = f }
     | val Int: Int = 42
object f
val Int: Int = 42
```

Now when using *context bound* `:` notation

```
def foo[F[_]: Applicative]: F[Option[String]] = Applicative[F].pure(None)
```

we do not have the name of implicit value parameter to work with, so we cannot use the above convention trick and call

```
F.pure(None)
```

because, again, dot notation on types is strictly speaking illegal, so instead we use the companion object with main method trick

```
Applicative[F].pure(None)
```

This works because `Applicative` companion has something like

```
Applicative {
  def apply[F[_]](implicit instance: Applicative[F]): Applicative[F] = instance
}
```

so calling

```
Applicative.apply[F]
```

or shorter

```
Applicative[F]
```

returns the implicit `instance` in scope. At this point we do have our *value* to work with and so dot notation becomes legal

```
Applicative[F].pure(None)
              |
    ok because invoked on a value
```

Therefore, you have to call with `Sync[F].pure(None)` instead of `F.pure(None)`, because in your particular case, you are using context bounds.

Comment: Could you please explain the differences between **Types** and **Values** with the `F` context.  The example `def foo[F[_]](implicit F: Applicative[F]): F[Option[String]] = F.pure(None)`, why is `F` also a value?

Comment: @zero_coding Consider why the following is legal: `val Int: Int = 42`. Here `Int` is the name used for both a value and a type.

Comment: Because `Int` is a value and at the same time also a `Type`. @Mario Galic man you are awesome.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a minimised example of the issue that shows the import that brings in the `pure` extension method:

```
scala> import cats.Applicative, cats.implicits._
import cats.Applicative
import cats.implicits._

scala> def foo[F[_]: Applicative]: F[Option[String]] = None.pure[F]
                                                            ^
   error: type mismatch;
    found   : F[None.type]
    required: F[Option[String]]
   Note: None.type <: Option[String], but type F is invariant in type _.
   You may wish to define _ as +_ instead. (SLS 4.5)
```

The problem is that the type of `None.pure[F]` is inferred to be `F[None.type]`, without the expected return type influencing inference. If you desugar the context bound and extension method, type inference will work as you expect:

```
scala> def foo[F[_]](implicit F: Applicative[F]): F[Option[String]] = F.pure(None)
def foo[F[_]](implicit F: cats.Applicative[F]): F[Option[String]]
```

You could also write out something like `Option.empty[String].pure[F]`, etc.—there are a lot of ways to run into this kind of issue (too-precise type inference), and a lot of ways to work around it, and which you should choose is mostly a matter of taste.

Comment: On my example above, I have changed to `override def get(v: env.EnvVariable): F[Option[env.EnvValue]] = F.pure(None)` and got the error message `not found: value F`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does `x.type` mean in Scala?

Comment: @zero_coding If you want to refer to `F` explicitly, you need to use an implicit parameter list (as in my second example above) instead of the context bound (`F[_]: Applicative`). `x.type` is the singleton type of `x`, which in the case of `None.type` is the type with `None` as its only member.